# Check a string to see if it is a palindrome

Tags: c#, palindrome, comparative-review

I have written two code pieces  to check if a given string is a palindrome:

```
public static bool FirstMethod(string str)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = str.Length - 1;

    while (i<j)
    {
        if (str[i] != str[j])
            return false;

        i++;
        j--;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```
public static bool SecondMethod(string myString)
{
    string first = myString.Substring(0, myString.Length / 2);
    char[] arr = myString.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    string temp = new string(arr);
    string second = temp.Substring(0, temp.Length / 2);
    return first.Equals(second);
}
```

Please tell me which one is better.

Is there a better method than this?

Comment: I'm not sure either of the methods proposed is an actual valid response.

Wikipedia defines a palindrome as :

A palindrome is a word, phrase, number, or other sequence of symbols or elements that reads the same forward or reversed, with general allowances for adjustments to punctuation and word dividers. Famous examples include "Amor, Roma", "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama" and "No 'x' in 'Nixon'".
Neither of the the methods deals with the removal of punctuation or spaces.

Comment: How about a regular expression?

Comment: Now write a version that takes into account UTF-16 surrogate pairs and Unicode combining characters :-)

Comment: @svick and what that would be like ?

Comment: How important is performance to you? For readability, I prefer a straight-forward solution: `myString == new String(myString.Reverse().ToArray());`

Comment: @svick could just normalize the string beforehand? Then all surrogate pairs and combining characters will become consistent

Comment: Have a look at www.unicode.org. The information there is _essential_ if you ever want to do any non-trivial programming. @Lukazoid: No, that doesn't help, because trivial code will compare characters consisting of more than one unit in the wrong order. Just a trivial letter A with umlaut in UTF-8 won't work.

Comment: @gnasher729 Ah yes, the combining characters would be compared in the wrong order, silly me

Comment: @Lukazoid The problem is that you can't just do a character by character reversal of utf-16 (or traverse it backwards) and arrive at a still valid string. To be fair C# without extra libraries just isn't really up to the task to deal with surrogates, etc. so that would be quite annoying to implement correctly..

Comment: @Voo I am aware, I've done quite a bit of work with C# and unicode graphemes, just had a dud moment

Comment: @Voo I once implemented that using only the methods of the `char` type, and in was indeed annoying. But later I learned of the `StringInfo` class which handles splitting a string into text elements. Using it a [unicode aware solution](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0e736db5ba37175af8c3) is barely more complex than the naive approach.

Comment: @CodesInChaos That's nice. Haven't looked into it so not sure how complete it is (I'm using the ICU library for Java as the benchmark here) but better built-in unicode support is something that I still miss in every mainstream language. Thanks for pointing that class out. But if your solution really handles surrogates and everything, that's top-notch from a LOC point of view!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would prefer the first one for a few reasons.

1. It's more readable and easily understandable in my opinion.
2. There's only one string, so less overhead. (Which is negligible unless this is being called **a lot**.)
3. There's only one array. [Reverse creates a second array.](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Array@cs/2/Array@cs)

That being said, an actual review is in order.

- Methods that return a boolean value should have names of the form `IsSomething` or `HasSomething`. A great name would be `IsPalindrome`.
- Neither method accepts anything but a string. [Numbers can be palindromic too.](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Palindromic_number) Wouldn't it be a nice addition if we could pass an integer to it as well? (Without explicitly calling `.ToString()` before passing it in that is.)
- I like that you're only checking for `i < j` instead of `i <= j`. It saves a useless iteration when there are an odd number of characters.
- I also like the `while` loop. It's a lot cleaner than the `for` loop suggested by another answer.
- I won't speak much on the second method, because I think [@elios provided a nice implementation of it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/58399/41243).

Comment: In my actual code the name of FirstMethod is "IsPalindrome" I named it this way just for the question purpose :)...for the second point yes I failed to check it for palindrome numbers..and for the third point initially I added i<=j then I realized for odd number of characters the middle value would be the same..thanks for pointing out though

Comment: I figured as much @kyle, but I had to mention it.

Comment: I actually believe that **not** checking palindromic numbers is a **good** thing.  First of all, it means you have to write less code.  Second, I reject the assumption that numbers themselves can be palindromic.  For instance, 22 would be a so-called palindromic number.  However, 22 is 10110 in binary, which is not palindromic.  To check if a number is palindromic, you need to know the number system (base 10, base 2, base 16).

Comment: I just thought it would be a nice extension to the code @SjoerdJobPostmus. Nothing to get wound up about. Although, it's a bit silly to reject the fact that numbers can be palindromic. Yes, you need to know what base it is, but don't you have to know what language a string is? Racecar in french is "voiture de course".

Comment: It would be a nice extension, that I agree on.  I was afraid however that it came across as something one must do, instead of as a feature one could add, and if so, only after the need has been discovered. However, for accepting a number, I do think that one should expect a base to be supplied, optionally defaulting to 10 if the language supports it.  (By the way, I upvoted.  I completely agree with all the other remarks.)

Comment: @ckuhn203: About the "racecar" vs "voiture de course", I do not think this is comparable to needing to know the base.  A number in and by itself is not something consisting of separate entities, and only by choosing a representation (binary, decimal, hexadecimal), do we get something that consist of an ordered list of entities.  The number one hundred and twenty-one becomes the entities 1, 2, 1 (in precisely that order).  That does me to think to add that not only strings can be palindromic, but any list of items (supporting equality).  The algorithm chosen would still be my choice for this.

Comment: @SjoerdJobPostmus racecar in Spanish or French probably isn't a palidrome... didn't mean it isn't one in English. Why worry about number base anyways?

Comment: Numbers themselves can't be palindromic, only their string representation in a specific base.

Comment: @WernerCD, racecar in french is a different word to racecar in english. Whereas 0xF and 15 are the same number and mean the same thing. `equal(15, 0xF)` is true, but `equal("racecar", "voiture de course")` is false.

Comment: @Jonathan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome - `A palindrome is a word, phrase, **number**, or other sequence of symbols or elements that reads the same forward or reversed` (emphasis mine). Other dictionaries have the same definition. You're arguing semantics, but the commonly accepted definition includes numbers. Just because something isn't a palindrome in another "language" (french) or "base" (binary/hex/etc) doesn't mean it stops being a palindrome in English or base 10. 1881 is a palindrome in base 10 or hex... what does it matter if it isn't one in binary? Honestly...

Comment: @WernerCD As we all know wikipedia is the authoritative source of information now, right? :-) A *number* cannot be a palindrome, only the *representation* of a number can be.  Which is really obvious: Is "axxa" a palindrome? Yes. Is the number that is represented by "(11)10" a palindrome? If you say yes I'll just point out that the given number is equal to "(1011)2" which isn't a palindrome. Hence a number cannot be a palindrome because that would make the answer inconsistent depending on which representation you use.. which again is obviously in violation with basic math axioms.

Comment: cont. Also the oxford dictionary defines a palindrome much more sensibly as "A word, phrase, or sequence that reads the same backwards as forwards". And the statement "you're arguing semantics" in a discussion about the meaning of a word was ironic right? Quite a lot of people also think that "irregardless" is an existing word and makes sense semantically - doesn't mean they're right.

Comment: Comments are not the place for extended discussion. I get a notification (as does OP ) for every comment. Please take this to chat. I'd be happy to create a room if you need one.

Comment: @WernerCD, "number" can mean different things in different contexts. in some cases it is the symbols that are written, in other cases it is the values. In the wikipedia it is the former, this is obvious by "or other sequence of symbols or elements", it's clearly not talking about number-as-in-value. In code number means the value, because we write in base 10 or 16 etc, but the computer only understands binary. You need to separate the value/meaning from the sequence of symbols we have chosen to describe it. palindromic is a property of representations not value.

Comment: Since this continues to drag on, I'll point out that there are [mathematical ways to find palindromic numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/502092/155159). Seems relevant @Jonathan.

Answer (score 18):

Here is the most common solution for this problem:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    char[] array = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(array);
    string backwards = new string(array);

    return s == backwards;
}
```

and if you are using Linq:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    return s == new string(s.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

but if you are planning to execute this code thousands of times (which I doubt), your first method would be the fastest.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with @ckuhn203 in that the first looks cleaner.

I'm not too familiar with C# and its style, but in C I would definitely prefer using a `for` loop:

```
public static bool FirstMethod(string str)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = str.Length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        if (str[i] != str[j]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider using LINQ:

```
static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    var characterPairs = s.Zip(s.Reverse(), (l, r) => l == r);
    return characterPairs.Take(s.Length / 2).All(isMatch => isMatch);
}
```

Comment: there is no Reverse method in System.String

Comment: @elios264 `using System.Linq;`

Comment: dont thing you need to pass a lambda to All if it is going to be identity

Comment: @jk. I wish that were true. It would look cleaner. However... `Error 1 No overload for method 'All' takes 0 arguments`

Comment: @dss539 you are right! how peculiar that Any has that overload but All doesn't

Answer (score 4):

The first one is probably a bit faster, the second could be cleaned up a bit, but is easier to read. Unless you know you have a performance problem, prefer the second one.

For the second option, you should extract two sub-strings from the original input string called "firstHalf" and "secondHalf" corresponding to the first and second half of the input string respectively. Then reverse "secondHalf" and compare.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to write this using LINQ, though I'm not sure it's actually clearer:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / 2).All(i => str[i] == str[str.Length - i - 1])
```

Comment: finally a one line answer!

Comment: @elios264 My answer can also be one line, but I split it for readability.  `return s.Zip(s.Reverse(), (l,r)=>l==r).Take(s.Length/2).All(b=>b)`

Answer (score 2):

My computer science teacher would turn over if at least one person didn't respond with an example of recursion.  I'm not a C# guy myself, but if you wanted to nerd out I think that would work a little something like this:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(string str)
{
    int len = str.length - 1;

    return str[0] == str[len] && (
           len <= 1 || IsPalindrome( str.Substring(1,len) )
           );
}
```

As long as you are chopping up new strings you could potentially write this so that long strings could be distributed across multiple cores. That's a 1/number_of_cores improvement!

Answer (score 1):

I would add that you could make your method an extension method of string. It just emphasises that being a palindrome is a property of a string representation of some sort.

For ease of understanding, the second method stands out. The index based version works, but most people would scratch their heads if they saw it without a hint.

Also it's a premature optimisation to cut the string in half, even though of course it is logical. Much more clear to reverse and compare. If somehow it really is a bottleneck, then cut it in half.

Comment: I knew right away what that code was doing, why would people scratch their heads?

Comment: I agree with @Malachi. The first version is actually easier to read to my eyes. However, my original background was in C/C++ so maybe that's why. The information density is higher. #2 looks like some Java Enterprise Architect wrote it. (not a bad thing necessarily)

Comment: The index manipulation version is not obvious at all. I'm assuming someone would be skimming the code, not parsing every little bit. You'd have to catch the fact that i and j are moving opposite to each other and have a think about why it stops when they cross. The second way actually says "reverse" in the code and compares.

Comment: @Carlos fair enough. I've seen that sort of code quite a lot so my mind actually filled in the code before even reading it (dangerous during code reviews!). I do agree that it might seem obtuse if you've not seen that pattern very often.

Comment: It's a pretty basic algorithm. If someone I worked with saw it and *didn't* understand it, I would be concerned about their level of ability. Loops and arrays should be one of the first things you learn as a programmer.

Comment: @ckuhn203 I think Carlos' point wasn't that he didn't understand it, but rather that it took longer to understand than version #2. I can easily see that being true for me if I did not have a background in C/C++.

Comment: @dss539, using the first implementation I can figure out what a palindrome is if I didn't already know, the second one is horribly messy compared to the first one, I have to decipher all those words, the first one is straight forward and more efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

Another shameless linq answer that doesn't require reversing or creating a new enumeration and only goes as far as it needs to:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(this string str)
{
    int len = str.Length;
    return str.Take(len / 2).All(o => o == str[--len]);
}
```